# How to fix error "Your credentials class does not support session injection. Performance will not be at the maximum." message when sending a message?

Tags: python, botframework

I'm using the python botbuilder-sdk and when the server sends any message it prints the following message to the console: 
`Your credentials class does not support session injection. Performance will not be at the maximum.`

I've tried just downloading the samples found on the [github](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/tree/master/samples) and the issue persisted.

This is what I currently have for sending the messages.

```py
credentials = MicrosoftAppCredentials(APP_ID, APP_PASSWORD)
connector = ConnectorClient(credentials, base_url=activity.service_url)
reply = self.buildReply(activity, activity.text)
connector.conversations.send_to_conversation(reply.conversation.id, reply)
```

The unknown message seems to result from the `send_to_conversation` function.

Any insight as to why its appearing would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to suppress the warning or do you want to support session injection?

Comment: I would like to support session injection especially since it says there is a performance drop associated with not supporting session injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python Bot Builder SDK uses `msrest-for-python`. You can see that the warning message is displayed if the credentials class doesn't contain a [`signed_session`](https://github.com/Azure/msrest-for-python/blob/master/msrest/pipeline/requests.py#L64) or a [`refresh_session`](https://github.com/Azure/msrest-for-python/blob/master/msrest/pipeline/requests.py#L79) method. You can see in the Bot Builder source code that [`MicrosoftAppCredentials`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/blob/master/libraries/botframework-connector/botframework/connector/auth/microsoft_app_credentials.py) does not contain either of these methods. With this information, you can raise an issue in the Bot Builder Python repo on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/issues